# how can i separate the last 4 numbers in a cell or the last eight if it has dash? also extract the middle part of the sentence?

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

These are 3 different items in 3 separate rows. Would like the results to return in the column next to it. the goal is to extract the years, ex:

```
2012-2014

2012-2013

2019
```

Below is the data km working with and each one is in a different row.

```
Sugar Coops (top) 2012-2014

Sugar Coops (bottom) 2012-2013

Red Apples 2019
```

for the middle extraction looking to take:

```
Coops (top)

coops (bottom)

apples
```

Unable to add pictures sorry. those cells would like to be able to extract the year(s) and the middle portion example coops (top). Essentially looking to break this sentence into 3 parts. First word in one column and another column the middle section etc

thank you!

Comment: It's bit confusing, please [Edit] your post & add some sample data along with expected output (the Screen Shot), help us to fix it!

Answer (score 2):

Your data looks "well-formed":  it follows a regular pattern, even if not immediately obvious, and does not look to have irregularities in that pattern.

1. The first thing you need is a single word. Not, for instance, a first name field that can actually have multiple words separated by a space. So the space following it is easy and accurate to use as a marker for the end of the word.
2. The last thing you need from the data is the same except the space precedes the string you need. The trick here will be figuring out how Excel will tell where that is so it can start extracting that string. That's obnoixious, bet doable.
3. The third thing you need is... everything else. That can also be called "the original string with the first two things removed, then dressed up nicely." And THAT is doable as well.

So, the first part, the first word in the data:  Just use the `LEFT()` function and tell it to stop right before the space. You can learn where the space is with Excel's `FIND()` function and subtract 1 from the value it returns:

```
=LEFT( A1, FIND( " ", A1 ) - 1 )      (Put in B1, say.)
```

(I'll be using A1 as the cell with the data string being pulled apart. Excel will find the space, subtract 1, then take that many characters from the left of the string. All done.

The second part will be discussed after the third part. So how do you find the LAST space in a string. There are a variety of ways, especially if you know VBA and are allowed to use it. The following is the simplest of all, really, nothing bizarre and hard to understand about the formula, no difficulty getting the result, no Named Ranges, just a simple combination of simple and standard functions:  `RIGHT()` (like we used `LEFT()` a moment ago, `FIND()` which we also used, and `SUBSTITUTE()`.

Why not just `FIND()` for that final space? Well, `FIND()` won't look for, say, the 9th space. It will look starting at character 2,174 if you want, but it won't look for the 3rd space or the 7th space. So you need to tell it where to start. Trouble is, no `FUNCTION()` will really tell you where that is. But if you were looking for a pretty unique character, so there'd only be one of them, no matter what, `FIND()` will happily find it and tell you where to begin taking the data you really want. (To use it to tell `RIGHT()~ how many characters to take, you will add 1 to it, but you get the idea.)`SUBSTITUTE()` though, is happy to replace the 3rd or 4th or 232nd "something" in a string. (A string, not a cell:  you can even build strings in formulas that exist in no cell at all, and use it on them!) How to find out which x'th one that is?

If you know the length of the string in the cell, and use something like `SUBSTITUTE()` to remove all the spaces (since we want to know which'th space to use) then the NEW length will be less by however many that is. Subtracting it from the original length will tell you how many spaces. So if there are 251, you want the 251st space and can feed this result to `SUBSTITUTE()` to tell it which instance to use. Lots of things being substituted here, but they're all different, so pretty easy to keep track of.

So several of `SUBSTITUTE()` to place that unique character, `FIND()` to get its place in the string, add one to get the beginning of your desired data, and `RIGHT()` to actually collect it (with another assist from `LEN()`). Like this:

```
=RIGHT( A1, LEN(A1) - FIND( "¢", SUBSTITUTE(A1, " ", "¢", LEN(A1)-LEN( SUBSTITUTE( A1, " ", "" )))))      (Put this in D1.)
```

So now you have the first and third things. If only Excel did "string math" and you could "subtract" those from the original data! Well you can, in a straightforward way, and then dress the result up.

If you use `SUBSTITUTE()` again, twice in the same formula, the first one looking for the contents of B1 and substituting a blank for that in the original string, and the second one doing the same with D1's contents, you have the middle stuff which is almost what you need. Presumably you so not want those first or last spaces to lead and trail it, so to get rid of them you have two choices:  instead of removing just B1's (and D1's) contents, you tell `SUBSTITUTE()` to remove a string of each one AND a space. Works here, but it isn't a wonderful general solution.

Excel has a function, `TRIM()`, that will remove initial spaces, trailing spaces, and also "clean out" any extra spaces inside a string. (NOT single spaces by themselves in a string! Rather, if there are sets of 2, 3, 4, 2,175 spaces in a row, it will reduce them to single spaces.) `TRIM()` will nicely remove the two spaces that will be left because they start and end the string. A downside would be removing spaces INSIDE the string, if they could happen and need to be preserved (it's cool if they need to go, eh?). So choose `TRIM()` if that is not a concern, or tack the spaces onto the B1 and D1 contents for removal if it is a concern. I'll assume it is not in the following:

```
=TRIM( SUBSTITUTE( SUBSTITUTE( A1, B1, "" ), D1, "" ) )      (Put in C1)
```

Notice how the inner `SUBSTITUTE()` removes B1's contents and then that resulting string is the material the outer one works on? It removes D1's material, then `TRIM()` takes off the leading space and the one at the end.

Finally, consider the last issue which is those year values. Do you want some being text, starting at the left edge of the cell, and some being numbers, starting at the right edge of the cell and edging left? Well, that's a concern sometimes. Not here though. When Excel gives you a return from a string function like `LEFT()` or `RIGHT()`, it treats the result as text. So they will all behave as text and most other functions that look at them (like `VLOOKUP()` for instance) will also regard them as text. Some won't though...

So a lookup like `VLOOKUP()` will fail to find "2014" if it is searching using a text value. Hard to figure out why it's failing if you are seeing it or hearing about it a year after you do this. If you use its approximate feature, it can be even harder because "2016-2018" will not seem to follow a bare "2016" in Excel's mind. You can cover yourself by wrapping a `TEXT()` function around ALL of column D's results like so:

```
=TEXT( D1, "@" )
```

(In reality, instead of "D1" you'd use the formula above that was for the D column.)

That makes Excel see EVERYTHING in the column as text without formatting the column as text (because... then the formulas in it wouldn't work... eh?). You use the "@" format so that the text results come out just fine.

Now Excel will STILL let some functions see the values in column D as numbers (if they are) but only ones that don't cause problems for the most part. Lookup functions, for example, will now work properly (so long as you remember to make their search values text too!).

Quite a number of other ways to do it, some pretty slick, many with VBA, even a UDF (User Defined Function). But this is awfully simple. The length is just the explanations, not the work.